# Couldn't find executable named camaracalibrator.py [ROS]

Tags: ros, camera-calibration

I am new to ROS and its developing. By following [this](https://qiita.com/proton_lattice/items/aa805b28700575ba5ed3) link. i try to calibrate uvc camera. Installation of calibration package and Installation of uvc_camera package are done. After i try to run

```
rosrun camera_calibration camaracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image: = / image_raw
```

i get following errors . Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
rosrun camera_calibration camaracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image: = / image_raw
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named camaracalibrator.py below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/camera_calibration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*camaracalibrator.py* is not spelled correctly. Change it to *cam**e**racalibrator.py*.

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image:=/image_raw
```

Try to use the autocompletion (by double hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> during input) to prevent problems like this in future.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It runs. Black window comes. black window keep as it is any idea please. The output 
https://ibb.co/h2hmmfk

Comment: Are you able to watch the image using `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/image_raw`?

Comment: Whats the image encoding? You could check this by entering `rostopic echo /image_raw/encoding` in your terminal.

Comment: it says WARNING:Topic [/image_raw/encording] does not appear to be published yet. Thank you.

Comment: Check the spelling. There is is a typo in `encoding`

Comment: i checked with rostopic echo /image_raw , there data is coming. and for image_raw/encoding "rgb8" --- is coming

Comment: rgb8 should be no problem. Typically the black window indicates no incoming images. Are you sure the image topic is correct?

Answer (score 0):

go to your file location (using the terminal) and make the file executable using the statement:

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```